# How to cache recycler view items once loaded

Tags: android, image, caching, android-recyclerview

I am creating a Xamarin.Android application using MvvmCross framework.
I am currently using RecyclerViews to show a list of data and images, but once the item is out of the frame and loaded again it also loads the images.
I don't want that to happen, I want the images to be cached once loaded.
If anyone has any idea about how can I acheive that? I will thankful.

Comment: Use an Image Caching & Loading library, not sure about Xamarin but there are libraries like `Glide`, `Picasso` & `Coil` (with coroutines).

Comment: Thanks @DarShan, will try using glide.